# ¿Cuál es la puntuación más común para los números?

Tags: puntuación, números, español-neutral

Hay dos formas más comunes de puntuación para los números.  Como en inglés:

> 1,000.00

O como en muchas partes de Europa:

> 1.000,00

Entiendo que las dos formas existen en español. Ya tengo un blog en español, y quiero saber cuál forma es la más "universal" o la más común.

Por el momento, la mayoría de mis lectores están en, o son de México y Centroamérica, pero el tema de mi blog es relevante para todos los países, entonces quiero usar la forma más usada.

Comment: Una vez que has entendido que no es un error usar cualquiera de ambas formas en ese contexto, tal vez te falta saber la forma empleada tradicionalmente en los materiales escolares: 1.000'00€ (con el punto como separador de millares y la "coma" decimal elevada (como un apóstrofe).

Answer (score 6):

La segunda forma, creo, es la más común por ser la forma tradicional, pero en el área que mencionas, es la primera por influencia anglosajona.

Por esta razón (de existir dos formas), la RAE recomienda la forma científica con espacios (finos, a ser posible) entre miles, y punto o coma (con preferencia por punto) después de las unidades como `1 234 567.89`

Sin duda, puedes usar cualquier de las formas y la gente te entenderán en los pocos casos ambiguos si siempre la usas, pero te dejo con lo que dice la [Ortografía 2010](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UGJUpDmIUKYymib,):

> Al igual que se hizo con la forma de separar los grupos de tres cifras en la parte entera de los números, los organismos internacionales de normalización han intentado establecer un uso general común para marcar la separación entre la parte entera y la parte decimal, inclinándose por dar preferencia a la coma en todos los documentos de difusión internacional.  Así lo establecer la ISO en su norma ISO 31-0, al igual que la Conferencia General de Pesos y Medidas […] No obstante, este último organismo decidió admitir ambos signos en su vigesimosegunda reunión […] reconociendo que la recomendación puede entrar en conflicto con la costumbre asentada en la lenguas o países que usan para ello el punto.
>
> En el ámbito hispánico, el uso de cada uno de estos signos se distribuye geográficamente casi a partes iguales: la coma se emplea en la Argentina, Chile, Colombia, el Ecuador, España, el Paraguay, el Perú y el Uruguay; mientras que se usa el punto en México, Guatemala, Honduras, Nicaragua, Panamá, Puerto Rico, la República Dominicana y Venezuela, así como entre los hispanohablantes estadounidenses; hay también países, como Bolivia, Costa Rica, Cuba y El Salvador, donde se utilizan ambos.  Con el fin de promover un proceso tendente hacia la unificación, **se recomienda el uso del punto como signo separador de los decimales.**

Yo creo que haya errado en preferir el punto, dejando que la influencia anglófona crezca, pero ¿qué se le puede hacer?  Ah...seguir usando la coma ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Es la segunda forma. Aunque las dos son válidas.

```
1.000,00
```

Comment: Esta es la que usamos en Chile siempre. La inversa sólo la entenderían personas con conocimientos de comercio exterior o informática.

Answer (score 1):

Ambos son correctos. Según [la RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS):

> \2. Ortografía de los números escritos con cifras. Para escribir correctamente los números expresados en cifras, debe tenerse en cuenta
>   lo siguiente:
>
> a) Al escribir números de más de cuatro cifras, se agruparán estas
>   de tres en tres, empezando por la derecha, y separando los grupos por
>   espacios en blanco: *8 327 451* (y no por puntos o comas, como,
>   dependiendo de las zonas, se hacía hasta ahora: 8.327.451; 8,327,451).
>   Los números de cuatro cifras se escriben sin espacios de separación:
>   *2458* (no 2 458). En ningún caso deben repartirse en líneas diferentes las cifras que componen un número: 8 327 / 451.
>
> ...
>
> c) **Para separar la parte entera de la decimal debe usarse la coma**,
>   según establece la normativa internacional: *El valor de π es 3,1416*.
>   **No obstante, también se admite el uso anglosajón del punto**, extendido en algunos países americanos: *El valor de π es 3.1416*.

Así que ambos son correctos y tal vez sea más indicado usar el punto por el perfil de tus lectores.

Comment: El DPD en este caso no está actualizado con la nueva Ortografía que, a diferencia de lo dicho, (tristemente) prefiere la forma anglosajona (aunque sin descartar la tradicional).

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, @guifa . ¿Podrías indicarme alguna referencia al respecto?

Comment: edité mi respuesta

Comment: @guifa muchas gracias :) ¡Más vale tarde que nunca!