# ¿Cómo se escribe la enumeración de números con parte decimal?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, español-neutral, números

Imaginemos que enumeramos cifras. Lo que haríamos sería escribir algo así como:

> Cuando estuvimos en México pasamos **2, 4 y 6** días en Ciudad de México, Tijuana y Sonora, respectivamente.

Es decir, enumeramos las cifras separándolas por una coma.

Sin embargo, si estos números tienen parte decimal la cosa resulta confusa:

> Para preparar la receta se necesitan **1,5, 2,5 y 2,5** cucharadas de azúcar, aceite y harina, respectivamente.

<sub>Vale, ya sé que el ejemplo suena un poco forzado, no se me ocurrió otro :)</sub>

En efecto, vemos que la parte de *1,5, 2,5 y 2,5* tiene muchas comas y puede resultar difícil saber si una coma sirve de separador de cifras o para delimitar la parte decimal.

Entonces mi duda es: ¿cómo se escribe en este caso?

Nótese que el DPD en [*números*](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS) dice:

> 2. Ortografía de los números escritos con cifras
>   c) Para separar la parte entera de la decimal debe usarse la coma, según establece la normativa internacional: *El valor de π es 3,1416*. No obstante, también se admite el uso anglosajón del punto, extendido en algunos países americanos: *El valor de π es 3.1416*.

Por tanto, entiendo que la duda está centrada en España, donde no sé si entonces la recomendación es de adoptar el uso anglosajón.

Además, hace un tiempo [guifa comentó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13093/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-puntuaci%C3%B3n-m%C3%A1s-com%C3%BAn-para-los-n%C3%BAmeros/13104#comment15676_13104):

> la nueva Ortografía (...) (tristemente) prefiere la forma anglosajona (aunque sin descartar la tradicional).

Por lo que no sé si el DPD actualmente sugiere alguna cosa nueva.

Comment: Sobre la posición de la coma (arriba o abajo) que comentan walen y blonfu, en Wikipedia (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal#Ap%C3%B3strofo) indican que la posición alta (3'14) **era correcta**, y algo más abajo, en el apartado de *Ejemplos de uso* ponen: "1.234.567'89: España (escritura a mano, hasta principios de 1980, desaconsejado por la RAE)"

Comment: Tambien: 1,5; 2,5; 2,5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pues veamos qué es eso que dice la [Nueva Ortografía sobre el separador decimal](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KGthOVWshQlykqO,):

> En el ámbito hispánico, **el uso de cada uno de estos signos se distribuye geográficamente casi a partes iguales**: la coma se emplea en la Argentina, Chile, Colombia, el Ecuador, España, el Paraguay, el Perú y el Uruguay; mientras que se usa el punto en México, Guatemala, Honduras, Nicaragua, Panamá, Puerto Rico, la República Dominicana y Venezuela, así como entre los hispanohablantes estadounidenses; hay también países, como Bolivia, Costa Rica, Cuba y El Salvador, donde se utilizan ambos. Con el fin de promover un proceso tendente hacia la unificación, **se recomienda el uso del punto** como signo separador de los decimales.
>   Así pues, en español, según las zonas, **podrá escribirse** π = 3,1416 **o** π = 3.1416.

Es decir, que se recomienda el punto, pero se admiten ambos.

Así las cosas, y dado que en cualquier texto medio normal (y en enumeraciones especialmente) siempre va a haber más comas que puntos, creo que **la mejor solución en enumeraciones es usar puntos en vez de comas para evitar "cacografías"**. Lo cual te habría propuesto igualmente aun cuando la RAE no lo aceptase pero, si lo acepta y recomienda, mejor que mejor.

Personalmente veo mejor usar el punto siempre: se presta menos a confusión en textos escritos (por lo dicho), más aún ahora que los millares se separan mediante espacios y no mediante punto; facilita las cosas en entornos tecnológicos y científicos donde el formato anglosajón es prácticamente ubicuo; y lo llevamos viendo desde pequeños en las calculadoras, con lo que no nos resulta extraño. Pero eso es opinión personal.

Comment: A lo mejor me equivoco pero creo recordar que a mi me enseñaron a poner la coma arriba, un apostrofo vamos: 2'5. ¿Nunca ha sido correcto eso?

Comment: las notaciones de caracter cientifico o matematico van evolucionando con el paso del tiempo, afortunadamente los estandares internacionales cada vez son mas eficientes para poder obenter grafias entendibles

Answer (score 6):

Existe otra alternativa y es usar el punto y coma

Segun la RAE http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XAD3nkRJmD6NjdyDQ0

> 3. Usos
>
> a) Para separar los elementos de una enumeración cuando se trata de expresiones complejas que incluyen comas:

O sea que si las expresiones de la lista que se van a enumerar usan comas el punto y coma sería el signo que se usa para separarlas.

La misma RAE dice que: (resaltado mío)

> 2. El punto y coma es, de todos los signos de puntuación, **el que presenta un mayor grado de subjetividad en su empleo**, pues, en muchos casos, es posible optar, en su lugar, por otro signo de puntuación, como el punto y seguido, los dos puntos o la coma; pero esto no significa que el punto y coma sea un signo prescindible.

pero se podría pensar en el punto  y coma como "un nivel superior" de la coma, así:

> ...receta se necesitan 1,5; 2,5 y 2,5 cucharadas de azúcar, aceite y harina,...

Aunque oficialmente se dice que en Colombia usamos la coma para separar los decimales, la realidad es que el uso del punto es el más extendido por lo tanto no tenemos este problema.